# Opening old KDevelop files

Tags: kdevelop

I have some older KDevelop projects that I am trying to recompile.  The problem is that KDevelop4+ will not open `.kdevelop` files.  Only `.kdevelop4` files are listed when I select open project.

Is there any way that I can open my projects so that I can work with them again?

Comment: Try to open kdevelop with path to a project from terminal — does it print errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `kdevelop /path/to/kdevelop/file.kdevelop` in a terminal.  If you run KDevelop from the command line, it opens the file just fine.